# firefox doesn't respect javascript change of float direction

Tags: javascript, firefox, css-float

This code works in all the major browsers except firefox which says it has done what I ask, but it doesn't. It's driving me crazy. This is the full html, css and javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" >
<html>
<head>
<style type=text/css>
.CastPic
{
    position        :   relative;
    top     :   +0px;
    width       :   250px; 
    height  :   250px; 
    padding-top     :   25px;
    padding-left        :   25px;
    padding-right       :   25px;
    padding-bottom      :   25px;
    background-image        :   url('Cast photos/Fiona Colquhoun.jpg');
    background-color        :   ivory;
    background-repeat       :   no-repeat;
    background-position     :   center; 
    cursor          :   pointer;
    border-style        :   solid;
    border-width        :   12px;
    border-color        :   green;
    float           :   left;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function toggle()
{
if (document.getElementById("CastPic").style.float =="right")
{
    document.myForm.msg.value = "float is right"
    document.getElementById("CastPic").style.float="left"
    document.getElementById("CastPic").style.borderColor="red"
}
else
{
    document.myForm.msg.value = "float is left"
    document.getElementById("CastPic").style.float="right"
    document.getElementById("CastPic").style.borderColor="blue"
}
document.myForm.msg.value = 'float is now ' + document.getElementById("CastPic").style.float
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="CastPic" id="CastPic"></div>
<form name="myForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
<input type="text"   name="msg" value=""  size=65>
<input type="button" value="Switch"  onClick="toggle()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is of course only a test script - I extracted this bit just to see if anything else affected it. I can't see anything.

Tia
Adrian

Comment: Your code doesn't work in Opera, for sure.  It only works in Chrome and Safari because of https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77427

Answer (score 8):

http://www.iamseree.com/application-development/use-javascript-to-change-float-style

```
document.getElementById("CastPic").style.cssFloat="left"
```

Code alert!!