# Firefox strips out my float:left

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, css-float

In my Javascript I have some code that looks like this :

```
itemView.style.float = 'left';
```

In chrome the float:left comes up fine:

```
style="float: left; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; text-decoration: none; width: 155px; height: 30px; padding-left: 24px; padding-top: 9px; margin-top: -4px; background-color: white; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial";
```

However in Firefox it is missing

```
style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; text-decoration: none; width: 155px; height: 30px; padding-left: 24px; padding-top: 9px; margin-top: -4px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% white";
```

Comment: Can you add a complete code example? Especially helpful is a jsFiddle.net example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: i will try. let you know tomorrow

Comment: Are you looking at "View Source" or are you pulling the code from something like `Firebug` in Firefox?

Comment: are you sure your js executes in firefox?

Comment: Console errors on FF ?

Comment: itemView.style.float = 'left'; doesnt work use CSS to float your element.  have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290989/firefox-doesnt-respect-javascript-change-of-float-direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
itemView.style.cssFloat="left"
```

Here's a little more [about the cssFloat property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_cssfloat.asp).